# PHP Contact Form on IIS Server?

Tags: php, iis, joomla

I'm running a Joomla website where all the files are stored on an IIS Windows server, and I've created a PHP Contact Form, one of Joomla's modules.

For some reason, the Contact Form will not send out any mail. There is always an error, no matter what setting you change it to in Joomla (SMTP, Sendmail or PHP Mail Function). With PHP Mail function it says 'Cannot Instantiate Mail Function', and there are errors in the others too.

Has anybody encountered these errors before? is there someone who knows a solution to these errors? I'm 99% sure its because its running on IIS, as I've used the same module on a Joomla system before and it works (running on FTP web host).

Hope someone can help, if you need anymore info I'll be happy to share it.

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your issue is Joomla related. You may need to configure SMTP in your php.ini

Please see this [tutorial](http://www.ruhanirabin.com/php-sendmail-setup-with-smtp-iis-and-windows-servers/)

Comment: Thank you, so do you then change the mail settings of Joomla to use SMTP? Do you need a SMTP Username and pass, or can this be bypassed if you leave it blank?

Comment: Joomla will by default use smtp port 25 and no authentication. Check your Global configuration and make sure it matches your mail settings.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, the tutorial worked great. I appreciate it.